# Text editors are not working in javascript div pop up

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, lightbox, fancybox, fckeditor

when i try to integrate the social engine with ckeditor ( social engine style is pop up update ) i load the ckeditor in the pop up but it does not focusing the text area i think the javascript files are conflict with each other is any one kanow please tell me the solution

Comment: Oh yeah, this makes a *whole* lot of sense...

Comment: Welcome, karuppasamy. Question for you: how could anybody possibly answer this given the information you've provided?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are having a problem with.  However, I did have a problem with ckeditor inside of a jqueryui modal dialog.  For it to work right, I had to implement the dialog open method and instantiate the ckeditor in the open method.

Something like this:

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
    open: function(){
        //create ckeditor instance here
    }
});
```

Maybe you are having a similar issue with ckeditor.